# javascript add event to object class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object, events

i want to add event handler to object's class (with JQUERY), but i cannot find solution to my problem. I have code like this:

```
class Obstacle
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.points = [];
    }
}

class Editor
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.obstacle = new Obstacle;
    }

    addPoint()
    {
        this.obstacle.points.push(canvas.click( function(e) { return [e.clientX, e.clientY]; }));  
        alert(this.obstacle.points.length);
    }
}
```

Of course without any results, so i'm asking for any help :).

Comment: The return value of the event handler is never received anywhere, since the function you pass to `click` method, _as an argument_, is called from the event queue (or in this particular case, inside jQuery). What is pushed to the array is the return value of `.click` call, and that's done only once, when you've called `addPoint()`. You've to push the coordinates to the array inside the event handler function.

Comment: and, how it should be done? Actually i think that was my first idea, i tried to make that:
    `canvas.click(function(e) { this.obstacle.points.push([e.clientX, e.clientY])})`, but error occured that push method was not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to push the coordinates inside the event handler. In the current code there's no receiver to the return value from the event.

Because `this` in the click handler refers to the element the event is attached, you need a separate reference to `this`. A simple way is to store `this` value to a variable in the outer scope and use that to refer the actual object. Like this:

```
addPoint() {
  const that = this;
  canvas.click(function(e) {
    that.obstacle.points.push([e.clientX, e.clientY]);
  });
}
```